# Is there any way to get route polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google

I have trying to find way to get google map display route polygon, so that i can filter data from my database(using polygon):

[Google directionsService.route](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints)

There is some option I found but it is not helpful because it is related with google map : [drawing tools polygon](http://jsfiddle.net/EdZk4/show/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution to get polygon for google map route here i have found solution using [script jsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369363/how-to-draw-a-polygon-around-a-polyline-in-javascript)